# sound / noise pollution data

Tags: data, remote-sensing

I'm looking for a geo-database on noise or sound pollution, ideally covering the area of one full country or more, e.g. measuring noise in dB. I am not interested in under-water noise pollution!

I am not sure whether there are ways of remote-sensing something like this, but if there are, does such a data set exist?

Comment: You can probably get point-sampled noise data or modelled noise data extrapolated from points based on distance to roads, trains, airports and terrain. Am trying to find a UK noise pollution map made by DEFRA but it seems to have been pulled. Noise is tricky because it is very time-varying and subjective...

Answer (score 3):

http://environment.data.gov.uk/ds/catalogue/#/catalogue has a section of noise-related data from Defra. There seems to be a slight problem with that site at the moment if you go via https instead of http. But anyway, there is data on road and rail noise, as a shapefile or a WMS/WFS service. Here's a map of Manchester with some road noise data overlaid.

[image]

Metadata available here, for example:

https://data.gov.uk/dataset/road-noise-laeq-16h-england-round-21